# Want to send empty json string "{}" instead of "null"

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to handle http requests in my go api, in which i wish to send empty json string like

```
{"result": {}, "status": "failed"}
```

but when the mysql query returns zero rows, it return an output as

```
{"result": null, "status": "failed"}
```

Edit : This is the response struct i'm using:

```
type Resp struct {
  Result []map[string]interface{} `json:"result"`
  Status string                   `json:"status"`
}
```

How can i handle this situation?

Comment: What are the types definitions for what you’re encoding?

Comment: Are you using `string` for your struct that you pass to the sql driver? If so, try using `mysql.NullString`. Or vice versa (don't remember exactly).

Comment: @JimB, this is the response structure type Resp struct {
  Result  []map[string]interface{} `json:"result"'
  Status  string                   `json:"status"`
 }  edited the same in my question

Comment: You will not be able to get an output of  `{}` (an object). The type is a slice; so you will get a `[]` (an array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Result` field is a slice, which can be `nil`. This is rendered as `null` in JSON. To make it not `nil`, you will have to initialise it.

In addition, since `Result` is a slice, it will be marshalled to a JSON array (`[]`), not a JSON object (`{}`).

Example:

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "log"
  "os"
)

type Resp struct {
  Result []map[string]interface{} `json:"result"`
  Status string                   `json:"status"`
}

func main() {
  enc := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)

  fmt.Println("Empty Resp struct:")
  if err := enc.Encode(Resp{}); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  fmt.Println()

  fmt.Println("Initialised Result field:")
  if err := enc.Encode(Resp{Result: []map[string]interface{}{}}); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

}
```

Output:

```
Empty Resp struct:
{"result":null,"status":""}

Initialised Result field:
{"result":[],"status":""}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/9zmfH-180Zk